# Taxa de Rejeições vindo de endereços estranhos

Tags: google-analytics-api

Galera, to com um probleminha..
No começo deste ano comecei a receber um numero enorme de visitas de outros paises vindo de sites como:

Traffic2cash.xyz (Esse é o que tem mais)
Share-buttons.xyz
site34687.xyz

Entre outros, todos de outros paises e isso tem ferrado a minha taxa de rejeição no analytics para quase 90%. Da pra bloquear esse tipo de visita?

Comment: Encontrei dois artigos que podem te ajudar. Mas é preciso analisar o caso do seu site para ver como proceder. Wordpress tem um plugin que bloqueia. Pela amazon existem técnicas. Enfim, para bloquear é preciso analisar todas as variáveis.

[Link1](http://www.ohow.co/what-is-referrer-spam-how-stop-it-guide/)

[Link2](http://ads-blocker.com/block-referral-spam/)

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade o próprio Google Analytics tem uma funcionalidade que você pode usar para literalmente filtrar esses dados da vista da propriedade. São os filtros que você encontra dentro do Admim->Vista de propriedade->Fittros.

Você pode usar um Regex para bloquear em massa esses spam bots.